# Handle primary keys with leading zero in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, primary-key, javascript-objects

I am building a data visualization based on tables with a primary key consisting of up to 4 integers. Examples:

```
5
015
1234
```

Throughout the application I need to use a key convention for these entities and I am considering my options. My concern is that leading zero/es will be stripped away if developers are not paying enough attention to Type and errors will arise when performing lookups etc:

```
regions["15"];

regions : {
  "015" : {name: "ABC", ...}
}
```

How do you think I should handle this?
How do I prevent errors while at the same time not imposing barriers?

Comment: If you cast the key to an integer, will there be duplication? ie do you have 15, 015 and 0015 as keys?

Comment: So 15 should be mapped to 015, and 05 to 5? What exactly is the convention for the keys?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: one, the loss of leading zeros due to decimal conversions, and two, the fact that leading zeros indicate to javascript that you are dealing with an octal number with careless conversions (e.g. `parseInt` without a base).

The easiest way to avoid any problems is to provide another prefix character onto your keys in actual fact, an underscore, letter or any other character. In your API, you can strip these away you choose, while requiring the prefix character for advanced accessors.

By requiring developers to input the prefix character, you ensure that you always get a string, and that they build their 4-character numeric strings as strings.

Another alternative is to specifically type check in your access functions, but if you are providing native key access through `[]` this is not an option (until future versions of javascript provide `Object.observe` support).

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough call and there are pros and cons in both directions.

If you store data as an `object`, there is no problem code problem with leading zeros.

If, on the other hand, you try to access the data as an `array` then leading zeros will be stripped.  A coder not paying attention could easily make a mistake and access data the wrong way.  Unfortunately, the mistake could be made in either direction.  Neither choice is a silver bullet.

Last time I was in this situation, I decided to prefix all the keys with a constant character, as a reminder to other coders that these were `string` keys, rather than `numeric` keys, something like this:

```
regions : {
  "R015" : {name: "ABC", ...}
}
```

You could even set up a module and define your own getters and setters to add/remove the constant as needed.